# jenkins expression is evaluating to false when checking for file existance to run second stage

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, dsl

team,

I have my pipeline that runs two stages.

stage 1 creates a file under `/coverage-data/myfile` and this is `emptydir` shared volume mounted from pod spec.

stage 2 starts if this file exists.

result: always expression is evaluating to `FALSE` any hint? I want to start the stage when file is created and present on the node on which this pipeline is runing such that all container in stages has access to this file.

pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'label-coverage-cli'
    }

    environment {
        COVERAGE_FILE = fileExists '/coverage-data/myfile'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Code Coverage Tests') {
            steps {
                container('main') {
                        sh '''
                        ls -ltr /coverage-data/
                        unit-tests.sh
                        ls -ltr /coverage-data/myfile
                        '''.stripIndent()
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Code Coverage Scan') {
            when { expression { COVERAGE_FILE == 'true' } }
            steps {
                container('sonar-scan') {
                        sh '''
                        scan.sh
                        '''.stripIndent()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

pod spec that is mounting shared volume for all containers in all stages to write on and read from as `shared-data`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: sec
  volumes:
    - name: shared-data
      emptyDir: {}
  containers:
    - name: main
      image: registry/tci-sonar-scanner:latest
      volumeMounts:
      - name: shared-data
        mountPath: /coverage-data
      command:
        - /sbin/tini
      args:
        - --
        - sleep
        - infinity
    - name: sonar-scanner
      image: registry/sonarqube-scanner:4.7.0.2747
      volumeMounts:
      - name: shared-data
        mountPath: /coverage-data
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      command:
        - tail
      args:
      - "-f"
      - "/dev/null"
```

output also shows file was created as I can with `ls -ltr`

```
Stage "Code Coverage Tests"
    +ls -ltr /coverage-data/
    total 0
    + script...
    +ls -ltr /coverage-data/myfile

-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins  staff  0 Dec 17 09:25 /coverage-data/myfile

.
.
.
Stage "Code Coverage Scan" skipped due to when conditional
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fileExists` command will run on the workspace directory on the master node when using the kubernetes plugin. If you want to test for a file in the kubernetes agent pod then you'll need something like

```
fileExists = sh(script: "test -e /coverage-data/myfile", returnStatus: true) == 0
```